# React using script that is imported in head

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Hi guys I'm trying to make a jigsaw website using `react`. I found a library called `snapfit.js` that can generate simple jigsaws from a `png` file. The problem is that I need to get this script working in a `react component`.

Currently I import the `snapfit.js` file in my `index.html` and when I open the console in chrome I can see that snapfit got added to the window (`snapfit.window`). I cant seem to find a way to make use of it in my react component though.

Currently I have:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import mole from '../assets/mole.png'
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

export class PuzzelSnapfit extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Demonstration</h2>
        <div><img src={mole} onLoad={alert(this)} />

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PuzzelSnapfit
```

I also tried using react-helmet like this:

```
<div><img src={mole} onLoad={window.snapfit.add(this)} />
```

When I try executing it that way I get a `toUpperCase of undefined` error, so it seems that this is `undefined`. I also tried loading the image into state but then I also get a `undefined` error.

Any help would be appreciated because I really dont know what else I could try except for maybe injecten a html file into my component but that also has its downsides.

Comment: I wonder if your React component and image is loading before snapfit. Can you add an event listener: "window.addEventListener('load')" and then try to do something in your component? You can use the componentDidMount lifecycle

Comment: Hey @meesVDS did you find a solution to this or maybe an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can import external scripts into your react js files by using the import statement.

example (your file where you want to use `snapFitFunction1()` and `snapFitFunction2()`):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import mole from '../assets/mole.png'
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { snapFitFunction1, snapFitFunction2 } from './snapfit.js';
...
```

In your `snapfit.js` file, you should have a export statements for snapFitFunction1, and snapFitFunction2.

example (`snapfit.js`):

```
function snapFitFunction1() {
  console.log('Foo');
}

function snapFitFunction2() {
  console.log('Bar');
}


export snapFitFunction1;
export snapFitFunction2;
```

You may have to add exports for functions you want to use from the snapfit.js file.

Comment: It seems that the original author of snapfit compressed his code or something because snapfit.js contains no exports but one big eval()

Comment: You could pack that eval() function into a new function ```const myfunction = () => { eval( ... ) };``` and then export ```myfunction```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the external library in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead of React helmet like this:

```
const snapJs = (yourScriptPath) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = yourScriptPath
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}


componentDidMount () {
snapJs("snapfit.js")
}
```

If you prefer using **React Helmet** then this would be the correct way:

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
const PuzzelSnapfit = props => (
<div>
    <Helmet>
       <script src="snapfit.js" type="text/javascript" />
    </Helmet>
</div>
  
);
```